# How can I join a database and table where the database name is derived from a field in the current table?

Tags: mysql, database, select, search

I currently have a database server which stores a main database and, a table within that database has a structure similar to below

companies.companyInfo

```
ID | Name     | databaseName | otherinfo
---+----------+--------------+----------
0  | companyA | databaseA    | Extra1
1  | companyB | databaseB    | Extra2
```

and the company databases are as follows

databaseA.users

```
userID | Name    | Password  |  extra
-------+---------+-----------+---------
0      | user1   | pass1     | other1
1      | user2   | pass2     | other2
```

and databaseB is similar.

What I want to do is get user information from one of the usertable, but to be linked from the main database

So I want to do is some kind of subselect to get all user details, but feed the database name into the subselect from the companies.companyInfo table  query.

I'm stuck.. please help!

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear what you're after, but in principle one cannot use expressions (including the value of a field from a table lookup) as identifiers (e.g. name of a table or column).

One workaround is to 'prepare' a statement from a string containing the desired query; such a string can be constructed by concatenating into it expressions in the place of identifiers:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
  'SELECT * FROM `', REPLACE(databaseName, '`', '``'), '`.users'
) INTO @qry FROM companies.companyInfo WHERE ID = 1;

PREPARE stmt FROM @qry;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

However, it may be just as easy to obtain the database name in your application using one `SELECT` query, and then perform the same concatenation to issue the second query from there.

All of that said, perhaps your data structure needs further normalisation?  Why not combine all of the databases into one, with a column in each table indicating to which company each record relates?